# Define default value in OS field when creating new task in bugzilla

Tags: perl, product, default-value, bugzilla

I installed bugzilla 4.4 on linux server, and finished to define all groups and products.
I also defined kinds of OS and Hardware platforms. I am wondering if it is possible do define default OS or default hardware platform for specific Product.

I coudn't find any such option in the administartion page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the next steps:

## cd ..../bugzilla-4.4/template/en/custom/bug/create/

then you have to edit this file:

## vi create.html.tmpl

inside the file you have to find this peace of code:

```
<tr>
    [% INCLUDE bug/field.html.tmpl 
    bug = default, field = bug_fields.op_sys, editable = 1, 
    value = default.op_sys %]
</tr>
```

replace it with this code:

```
<tr>
   [% IF product.name == "ProductA" %]
     [% INCLUDE bug/field.html.tmpl 
       bug = default, field = bug_fields.op_sys, editable = 1, 
       value = "Android"  %]
   [% ELSIF product.name == "ProductB" %]
     [% INCLUDE bug/field.html.tmpl 
       bug = default, field = bug_fields.op_sys, editable = 1, 
       value = "iOS"  %]
   [% ELSE %]
     [% INCLUDE bug/field.html.tmpl 
       bug = default, field = bug_fields.op_sys, editable = 1, 
       value = default.op_sys %]
   [% END %]
</tr>
```